# Can you explain return in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return

How is return used in javascript ?

```
var makeNoise = function() {
  console.log("Pling!");
};

makeNoise();
// → Pling!

var power = function(base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
    result *= base;
  return result;
};

console.log(power(2, 10));
// → 1024
```

I am learning about functions in chapter 3 in eloquent javascript.

Comment: `return` returns a value, object, Boolean etc. if you set it in a function. When return is called it ends the functions there returning the result you set. By default JavaScript function return `void` (or nothing).

Comment: See [*MDN return statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible the best description ever. The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

Read from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

And I would recommend you visit www.codecademy.com they will help you learn faster and understand concepts easily

Answer (score 0):

When a function is invoked, it begins execution with the first statement and ends when it hits the } that closes the function body. That causes the function to return control to the part of the program that invoked the function.

The return statement can be used to cause the function to return early. When return is executed, the function returns immediately without executing the remaining statements.